# How to get a list of "Compile Sources" in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I want to get an Xcode variable that will list of all the files in the Compile Sources section of Xcode. I can't seem to find the [variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) for it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

In the "Run Script" phase for want to be able to iterate Compiled Source files and copy them to another location.

[image: Compile Sources]

Comment: Click the arrow next to the "Compile Sources" text?

Comment: I'm looking for the variable that can be used in the Run Script phase.

Comment: I can't seem to find any variable for the sources that are compiled, why exactly do you need to copy your sources that you compile? Perhaps you could try to use another build system, perhaps CMake? I think it does work with Obj-C (assuming you're using Obj-C?), although I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I'm running a script to copy the files to a remote computer via ssh and building on that machine. I just wrote a bash script and hardcoded the file paths. That is going to have to work for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer I can come up with at the moment is to hard code my list of file names into the bash script that I need them in.

Comment: There is some good insight in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326147/is-it-possible-to-sort-the-compile-sources-list-in-the-build-phases-section-of-a