# Is it possible to sort the Compile Sources list in the Build Phases section of an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

I want to sort the files in the 'Compile Sources' section of my Xcode project according to their names. Is it possible?

Comment: I want that too :-D Seems like currently they are "sorted" by rand()

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can reorder the **Compile Sources** section in Xcode, but not from the GUI - which is a shame considering that this is already version 6 of the IDE and they still haven't gotten around to this basic feature.

As A-Live said, you need to edit the **project.pbxproj** file within the **yourproject.xcodeproj** file. Use Finder to select the yourproject.xcodeproj file and then use the context menu to **Show Package Contents**. After that open the project.pbxproj file with a text editor.

Find the **PBXSourcesBuildPhase** section and copy everything between **files = (** and **);** into a new text file. Remove the leading tabs/spaces. Save that file somewhere on your disk. Open up a terminal and do this:

```
 sort -bf -t " " -k 3 PBXSourcesBuildPhase.txt > PBXSourcesBuildPhase.sorted.txt
```

Open up the new PBXSourcesBuildPhase.sorted.txt file in your text editor, copy the sorted lines into the **PBXSourcesBuildPhase** section of your **project.pbxproj** (overwrite the lines that you previously copied) and save.

Now you should be able to see all the files sorted in the **Compile Sources** section in Xcode.

I've tested this in Xcode 6.0.1 with a small project (~150 source files) and had no problems.

Careful: you should make a backup of your project file (or better: use version control) before you try this. Just in case.

Comment: Works like a charm. If you are a vim user just highlight the section and do `:'<,'>!sort -bf -t " " -k 3`

Comment: In any other editor you can also select the section, copy to clipboard and run `pbpaste | sort -bf -t " " -k 3 | pbcopy` in Terminal and then paste right over the original selection.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted solution works fine, but it requires manual steps(open the project file, find the section for the target that you want etc.) so it is a little cumbersome and it can not be automated if you need to keep the section sorted each time you perform a build or commit.
I faced with the same problem and I created a [ruby script](https://gist.github.com/csknns/c19793e8dfa059c494932d2ed1c7e8af) to sort these sections. The script sorts the 'Compile Sources', 'Copy Bundle Resources’ and all the 'Copy files' sections under Build Phase for a specified or all the targets.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'xcodeproj'
require 'set'

project_file, target_name = ARGV

# open the project
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_file)

# find the target
targets_to_sort = project.native_targets.select { |x| x.name == target_name || target_name.nil? }

phases_to_sort = [Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXSourcesBuildPhase, Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXCopyFilesBuildPhase, Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXResourcesBuildPhase]

targets_to_sort.each do |target|
  puts "sorting files for target #{target.name}"
  phases_to_sort.each do |phase_to_sort|
    target.build_phases.select { |x| x.class == phase_to_sort }.each do |phase|
      phase.files.sort! { |l, r| l.display_name <=> r.display_name }
    end
  end
end

puts 'saving project'
project.save
```

To sort all targets:

```
./sort_sources.rb MyProject.xcodeproj
```

Or to sort only one target:

```
./sort_sources.rb MyProject.xcodeproj My_Target
```

It requires the gem xcodeproj:

```
gem install xcodeproj
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 7):

I reckon it is a shame that this is not possible.

as a workaround in most of situations, you can use the search filter on the right upper corner of the file list.

for example, I needed to add a compiler flag in many files which (fortunately) all started with the same prefix. to do so, as stated [here](http://www.codeography.com/2011/10/10/making-arc-and-non-arc-play-nice.html), you have to double click on a file.

then, I filtered the files for the prefix, shift-clicked them in order to select them all, then released shift and double-clicked one of them. this way I was able to add the flag to all of the files at once

Comment: The workaround was really helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This is thoroughly answered, but I thought I'd share the [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) command that sorted these in place for me. Navigate to `project.pbxproj`, mark all files under `PBXSourcesBuildPhase`, and use the command:

`M-3 M-x sort-fields`

...aka sorting the marked area by the 3rd column, which happens to be the filenames. `C-x C-s` and you're on your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder the entries of `PBXSourcesBuildPhase` section at the `project.pbxproj`, it worked for me but of course there's no guarantee in general for it to work. Don't forget to backup your backups first.